# How can I find which process is using my GPU?

Tags: linux, nvidia

`nvidia-smi` displays "No running processes found". `lsof /dev/nvidia*` is empty. However, when I try to do `nvidia-smi -r` it says:

```
# nvidia-smi -r -i 0
GPU 00000000:xxxxxx is currently in use by another process.

1 device is currently being used by one or more other processes (e.g., Fabric Manager, CUDA application, graphics application such as an X server, or a monitoring application such as another instance of nvidia-smi). Please first kill all processes using this device and all compute applications running in the system.
```

How can I find which process is actually using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the message is kind of misleading. Just do `modprobe -r nvidia_drm` then the reset should work as expected.

Comment: Nope. `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia_drm is in use.`

Comment: U need to kill the process using drm before u do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to get a list of processes using the GPUs:

```
nvidia-smi pmon -c 1
```